# Hamburger Template: change default colors on Hamburger menu and pageheader, etc

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm an newbie when it comes to using Template 10. I'm building an app using the Hamburger template and I'm struggling with changing the default colors.
Below is what I find in the standard Custom.xaml file:

```
    <Color x:Key="CustomColor">SteelBlue</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContrastColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">SteelBlue</Color>
```

Changing it to:

```
   <Color x:Key="CustomColor">LightGrey</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContrastColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">LightGrey</Color>
```

Gives me the following error:

> Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Color' from the text 'LightGrey'.

What did I do wrong and how do I change the default color throughout the app?

Answer (score 3):

You have not spelled the color correctly. The correct spelling is the American form `LightGray` (replace the e with an a)

Answer (score 1):

The `Color` tag is used to create colors, from hex or RGB values. `LightGray` is already a color.

You can use the `LightGray` color in a brush

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="LightGray"/>
```

Comment: Changing to   <Color x:Key="CustomColor">LightGrey</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContrastColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">LightGrey</Color> gave me a runtime exception: WinRT information: Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Color' from the text 'LightGrey'. [Line: 20 Position: 63]

Comment: Its LightGray with an A